# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

In this line `url, endpos = get_next_target(page)`, it says ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in the terminal. 
I tried to split it but then realized the function `get_next_target` outputs a list so that wouldn't work.

```
def get_all_links(page): 
    links = [] 
    while True: 
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page) 
    if url: 
        links.append(url) 
        page = page[endpos:] 
    else: 
        break 
    return links
```

Comment: How many values are in the list from `get_next_target`?

Answer (score 2):

If `get_next_target(page)` returns a list then you can try this:

```
url, *endpos = get_next_target(page)
```

Or:

```
*url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
```

That way `*endpos` or `*url` will become a list. For example if `get_next_target(page)` returns [a, b, c, d] then `url` will be `a` and `endpos` will be `[b, c, d]`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, since it looks like OP is expecting `endpos` and `url` to be a single value instead of a list, you can do: `url, *middle_stuff, endpos = get_next_target(page)` to get `a`, `[b, c]`, and  `d`, although it is hard to tell what the OP wants exactly.

Comment: I did both options and for both it says slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method for the line page = page[endpos:]

Comment: Maybe you should post the values returned from `get_next_target(page)` so  we can know what we're dealing with.

Comment: Or `url, endpos = get_next_target(page)[:2]` if you only want first two items.

Answer (score 1):

You said it: get_next_target(page) is returning a list and it is trying to stick that list into url and endpos - 2 variables. Since it tells you "too many" that means the list has more than 2 elements.